# Issues saving and retrieving data from MS SQL Server with QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geometry, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

Wondering if anyone has issues with geometry not loading into QGIS when sourced from MS SQL Server for following specific case.

Software specifics:
MS SQL Server spatial :15.0.2000.5 Standard Edition (64-bit)
QGIS: 3.26.2

Steps:

1. A layer is loaded from MS SQL Server without any issues,
2. Fix geometries is run on QGIS,
3. Save the fixed temp layer back to SQL,
4. Close the project and reload the layer back in QGIS,
5. The geometry isn't rendered on QGIS and the attribute table (automatically filters) to 1 row.

I had a look at
a. [QGIS 3.16 MSSQL Server Primary Key Issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446274/qgis-3-16-mssql-server-primary-key-issue)
b. [MSSQL Data Not Showing Up in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74728/mssql-data-not-showing-up-in-qgis)
Both doesn't help.

What I've seen in the layer originating from QGIS is the data types for columns is based on ntext, float and datetime, where as the original layer has varchar, numeric and smalldatetime.
Looked here for info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext , but understand it has to do mostly with performance and MS planning to drop the data types in newer versions.

How can I do this?

Comment: The issue doesn't occur on the current LTR version of QGIS 3.22.13-3.

Comment: Several known bugs in QGIS, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261064/polygon-doesnt-appear-in-qgis, doesn't help either.